# Dynamic XML playlist for JW player with rtmp formatting.

Tags: php, mysql, xml, jwplayer

I am trying to randomize an JW Player xml playlist out of PHP/MySql database. 
I've gotten the playlist to almost work out of an array. If you refresh this page you'll see the playlist randomly updates from a database. http://spillway.com/radiotest/output7.php

The issue I have is the formatting of the xml for rtmp or Cloudfront with JW player.
The tag that currently works in XML is: 
`<jwplayer:source file="rtmp://s1hym70yk17nz2.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/Feathery_Husk.mp3">`

But this will not parse correctly in the dynamic xml. 
Would the JW Player  tag be preferable somehow?

Here is the working XML with Cloudfront which is hardcoded and works with a normal embed. http://spillway.com/radiotest/radio1.xml

Any Ideas would be great. Difficult to find consistent JW player data on any of this.

JFC

Answer (score 0):

I have a little script that makes a playlist random every time the page loads.

Demo - http://www.pluginsbyethan.com/github/randomplaylist.html

Instructions - https://github.com/emaxsaun/randomplaylist